# Setting empty text in kartik dynagrid

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Am using kartik dynagrid and i would like to setup a text that shows when the dataprovider returns empty

The grid

```
echo DynaGrid::widget([
            'columns' => $columns,
            'showPersonalize' => true,
         'emptyText'=>'Sorry all pr have pritems',///-----------------This is what i had set
            'options' => ['id' => 'assignsolic-grid'],
            'gridOptions' => [
                'options' => ['id' => 'grid'],
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                 'filterModel' => $searchModel,
                 'showPageSummary'=>false,
                'pager' => [
                    'firstPageLabel' => 'First',
                    'lastPageLabel' => 'Last',
                    'maxButtonCount' => 10,
                ],
                   'panel' => [
             'type' => GridView::TYPE_PRIMARY,
                       // 'heading' => '<h3 class="panel-title"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></i> </h3>',
                      'before'=>'<i>Select the Prs to assign solicitation and then click the Assign Solicitation button</i>',
                      'after' =>

        Html::button(' <i class=" glyphicon glyphicon-road "></i> Assign Solicitation ', ['value' => Url::to('assignsolc'),'class' => 'btn btn-danger', 'id' => 'assignsolic']),

                        'footer' => false
                    ],
                'toolbar' => [
                    ['content' => '{dynagridFilter}{dynagridSort}{dynagrid}'],
                    '{export}',
                    '{toggleData}'
                ],
                'pjax' => true,
                'bordered' => false,
                'striped' => true,
                'condensed' => true,
                'responsive' => true,
                'responsiveWrap' => false,
                'containerOptions'=>['style'=>'overflow:scroll'],
            ]
        ]) ;
```

This returs an error of Setting unknown property: kartik\dynagrid\DynaGrid::emptyText  how can i set the empty text

Comment: I use formatter in config/main.php... i have posted an asnwer .. hope is useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define  the value for null display  directly in  confi/main.php formatter component

```
'components' => [
   .......
        'formatter' => [
        'class' => 'yii\i18n\Formatter',
        'dateFormat' => 'dd.MM.yyyy',
        'decimalSeparator' => ',',
        'thousandSeparator' => ' ',
        'currencyCode' => 'EUR',
        'nullDisplay' => '',           // **** this param 
    ],
 .....
```

Otherwise  if the widget don't provide a proper attribute you can use  an anonymous function for value

```
  [
    'attribute' => 'your_attribute',
    'value' => function ($model) {
        if ( $model->your_attribute == NULL) {
            return  'Sorry all pr have pritems';
        } else {
            return $model->your_attribute;
       }
     },
  ],
```

Comment: I have several dynagrids and each dynagrid should have a different message

Comment: What do you mean by reference for dynagrid

Comment: Documentation .. .. tecnical reference ..  .. i know only this  http://demos.krajee.com/dynagrid and there are no info for emptyValue

Comment: Yes i have seen the documentation but they dont point on the null desplay setting the null display returns the error Setting unknown property: kartik\dynagrid\DynaGrid::nullDisplay i have also included formatter in the components

Comment: I would like the null message to be displayed in the content area where the data comes in and also probably not display the grid headers(colums) if the dataProvider is empty

Comment: Currently when the dataProvider is empty it returns No results found.

Comment: I have update  an answer with a suggestion .. but i'm evaluating other  solution too ... take a lool and let me know ..

Comment: I have check the doc .. at the moment the only way seems is the anonymous function  in value attribute

Comment: Thanks for that i have got an idea from it since am using $dataProvider i just have to check if it is empty by if ($dataProvider->totalCount > 0) { then add my message. Ill ,mark your ans as correct

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI   thank  ..  for this you can also use an infnull(your_column)  in select from database

Comment: i also had an earlier question on wbranca extension in yii2 failing to update kindly checkout  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38768439/error-in-wbranca-dynagrid-update

Comment: Could you please check a question i have posted on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38853443/changing-yii2-password-by-checking-the-current-password-with-the-entered-passwor

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI   .. Thank you for the confidence but unfortunately am not an expert in this

Answer (score 0):

Since am using $dataProvider i found out that i just have to check if the dataProvider is empty by

```
if (!$dataProvider->totalCount > 0) { pass in message to display }
 else{?>

  SHOW THE GRID HERE

 <?php
  }
  ?>

   ?>
```